# How to concatenate string when setting a parameter in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

First question here and is the following. I wrote the following code and everything works fine:

```
DECLARE @subject NVARCHAR(100)
SET @subject = 'Report executed on ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107)
SELECT @subject
```

Result: Report executed on Aug 17, 2012

but when trying to concatenate the previous string while setting the parameter of msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail procedure, it fails

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='XXX',
@recipients='XXXX@XXXXX.com',
@subject = 'Report executed on ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107),
@body= @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML';
```

I know I could declare and send a variable to the parameter but I would like to understand why it fails when concatenating directly in the parameter. thank you for your time and knowledge

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Parameter values to T-SQL stored procedures cannot be expressions. They need to be either a constant or a variable.

From [MSDN - Specify Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189260.aspx):

> The parameter values supplied with a procedure call must be constants
>   or a variable; a function name cannot be used as a parameter value.
>   Variables can be user-defined or system variables such as @@spid.

Comment: Bummer indeed.  I just want to pass in the results of a CONCAT call.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do:

```
DECLARE @Sub nvarchar(100);
SET @Sub = 'Report executed on ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107);
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='XXX',
@recipients='XXXX@XXXXX.com',
@subject = @Sub,
@body= @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML';
```

Comment: Thank you, I did know that passing a variable works, but I didn't understand why.